# Breakdown of /var/log/auth.log, what is ssh2?

Tags: server, ssh

I've used the command `grep sshd.\*Failed /var/log/auth.log | less` to check how much brute force traffic is on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS machine. I've noticed a few parts I don't understand.

```
Nov 21 12:55:53 *LOCALHOSTNAME* sshd[31151]: Failed password for invalid user john from *EXTERNAL IP* port 52162 ssh2
Nov 21 13:28:22 *LOCALHOSTNAME* sshd[31180]: Failed password for root from *EXTERNAL IP* port 47906 ssh2
Nov 21 13:37:03 *LOCALHOSTNAME* sshd[31186]: Failed password for root from *EXTERNAL IP* port 56522 ssh2
Nov 21 13:44:06 *LOCALHOSTNAME* sshd[31196]: Failed password for invalid user afar from *EXTERNAL IP* port 60040 ssh2
```

1) What is "sshd[port?]"?

2) What is "ssh2"?

Context:
This machine has been penetrated recently and used for botneting. I'm trying to be as proactive as possible this time around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(brute force)

This means that the selection attempt was made from EXTERNAL IP and was not successful.

```
  + Install 
  Fail2ban 
  DenyHosts
```

.....

[image: enter image description herd[1]]

```
lastb
```

---

**1) What is "sshd[port?]"?**

```
The authlog log file contains the following information:

• date and time: Feb 27 03:02:36;
• server name: bullit;
• remote access server: sshd;
• process pid: 18408;
• username: (phusermv);
• IP address: 77.222.44.2;
```

**2- What is "ssh2"?**

```
2 - SSH1 and SSH2 protocols / As already mentioned, sshd can work with the SSH1 and SSH2 protocols. However, the use of unsafe SSH1 is highly discouraged. You can make sshd work only with SSH2: Protocol
```

Comment: 2 -
SSH1 and SSH2 protocols
/
As already mentioned, sshd can work with the SSH1 and SSH2 protocols. However, the use of unsafe SSH1 is highly discouraged. You can make sshd work only with SSH2: Protocol 2

Comment: Is openssh-server the software I need to configure to accept ssh2 only? What about SSHD and the number in the [brackets] attached to it?

Comment: Added answer ++++